# Windows Form can't access PowerShell variable

Tags: windows, user-interface, powershell

I'm trying to display a PowerShell variable in a Windows form. I have a button and a label on the form. I can display the string return by TestFunction on the label but not on the Form pop up window.

This is my PowerShell script:

```
function TestFunction()
{
   return "PASSED"
}

Function Button_Click()
{
    $testResults = TestFunction
    $ResultLabel1.Text = $testResults ## this works - I can see "PASSED" 
    $TroubleButton1.Add_Click(
    {
        # This does not work
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($testResults)
    }
    )
}

## Call function
Button_Click
```

Why does the form think $testResults is NULL?

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to $global:testResults and it now works! Want to add it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You assign `$testResults` variable in `Button_Click` scope, thus you will lose that variable, when you leave that scope. You should save the variable in a scope, which will exists when you press `$TroubleButton1` button. Or you can pick value from `$ResultLabel1` label instead of variable:

```
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($ResultLabel1.Text)
```